# Create an array based on column values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe with title names as the column headers. I have a row which has counts the number of ratings for each title, and an another row with the median rating of each title. I want to create an array which holds the median ratings for titles with more than a certain number of ratings, is this possible?

For example the dataframe is set up like:

| Lion King | Mulan | Titanic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 57 | 76 | 63 |
| 2.5 | 4 | 3 |

and I want an array of the median ratings for movies who's total number of ratings are > 60, giving me [4,3]

I've tried using .loc and .iloc but it is not working the way that I expected. I cant find a good way online to take certain column values for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df.iloc[0] > 60` to create an array of Boolean values indicating whether each value in row 0 is greater than 60 (where df is your dataframe variable).

And you can use this to filter the values in your second row (`df.iloc[1]`) to get:

`df.iloc[1][df.iloc[0] > 60]`

It should return the pandas series:

```
Mulan      4.0
Titanic    3.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```